# Multiple Inheritance, each derived classes can override a operator from the base class and at the same time overwritten operator declared final

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, final

**My Goal is to declare `final` for the few/selected overwritten `operator`/`member function`.**

> BaseClass.h
>
> ```
> class BaseClass {
>     public:
>         virtual void baseClassOperator() = 0;
> }
> ```

> DeriveOneClass.h
>
> ```
> class DeriveOneClass : public BaseClass {
>     protected:
>         int varOne;
>        
>     public:
>         virtual int deriveOneClassOperator();
>         void baseClassOperator() final override; //REM; note: the keyword final here.
> }
> ```

> DeriveTwoClass.h
>
> ```
>  class DeriveTwoClass: protected DeriveOneClass, public BaseClass{
>     public:
>          virtual int deriveOneClassOperator() overrride;
>          void baseClassOperator() final override; //REM; And also in this line we 
>                                                   //REM; declared this operator as 
>                                                   //REM; final, so, no derived
>                                                   //REM; classes could override it.
>                                                   //REM; however this will create a 
>                                                   //REM; conflict between the 
>                                                   //REM; `DeriveOneClass` and 
>                                                   //REM; `BaseClass` implemented operators.
>                                                   //REM; The `DeriveOneClass` had a 
>                                                   //REM; final operator but 
>                                                   //REM; the `BaseClass` had a 
>                                                   //REM; pure virtual operator.
>                                                   //REM; what are the solution/fix? 
>  }
> ```

So then, when we want to have this "DeriveOneClass or DeriveTwoClass" as a Base class to the other classes, then we should not be able to override the declared final operators of those both specified classes. Similar to this syntax below;

> DeriveThreeClass.h
>
> ```
> class DeriveThreeClass : public DeriveOneClass {
>     public:
>        virtual int deriveOneClassOperator() override;
>        //void baseClassOperator() override; //REM; ERROR: cannot be overwritten
>                                             //REM; because 'FINAL' was declared
>                                             //REM; found at super/parent class
> }
> ```

So we could isolate/secure the operator(s) that are define and declare final, if we instantiate this as polymorphism;

```
BaseClass* bc = new DeriveThreeClass();
bc->baseClassOperator(); //REM; This one will invoke/call the 
                         //REM; DeriveOneClass overwritten baseClassOperator
                         //REM; or am I wrong?
```

However, sometime, we want to have those operators of base classes at the same time; such as the syntax example of `DeriveTwoClass` with two base classes, which are the `DeriveOneClass` and `BaseClass`. So when we have this syntax;

```
DeriveOneClass* doc = new DriveTwoClass();
doc->deriveOneClassOperator();
doc->baseClassOperator();

BaseClass* bc = doc;
bc->baseClassOperator();
```

***For all of these syntaxes, are they possible?***

Comment: Why are you inheriting `InterfaceClass` a 2nd time with `ClassTwo`??

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - Because I want like this `InterfaceClass ic = any_derived_class`. And then `ic.func()` and also I want to declared it `final`

Comment: Well, it's not possible to override a `final` function. That's exactly the purpose of that keyword, to inhibit that. You have to provide your own complete implementation for `InterfaceClass` without inheriting `ClassOne`. You may have an internal member of `ClassOne` though, to reuse whatever you want to reuse by delegation.

Comment: `InterfaceClass ic = any_derived_class;` cannot work, since `InterfaceClass` contains pure virtual functions. Furthermore even using a pointer to `InterfaceClass` wouldn't allow you to properly free a derived class, since there destructor of `InterfaceClass` is not virtual. The way you **can** rewrite that snippet which doesn't require you to inherit from `InterfaceClass` in `ClassTwo` to work is `InterfaceClass& ic = any_derived_class;` (just make sure the lifetime of `any_derived_class` doesn't end to soon).

Comment: With a virtual destructor in `InterfaceClass` you could to `std::unique_ptr<InterfaceClass> ic = std::make_unique<ClassTwo>();`

Comment: `ClassTwo` would contain two copies of `InterfaceClass`, so which one would a base class pointer point to? I think `final` is not the biggest problem here...

Comment: Either `ClassOne` should not make `func` final, **or** ClassTwo should not inherit from `ClassOne`.  Also, it is very odd for `func` in InterfaceClass to be `protected`.

Comment: @Eljay - your right on spot as a textbook, but what I need is a very specific structure. For the `func` at `InterfaceClass` to be protected the reason is I only want to declare/create an `Instance` of it inside of the scope of this `InterfaceClass`. I know it was a really tight coupling, but this is for Experimenting/debugging only.

Comment: You'll need to make `class ClassTwoHelper : public InterfaceClass` and implement the `func` there, and change `class ClassTwo : public ClassOne, public ClassTwoHelper`.  When I ran into a similar problem (in the 1990s), I chatted with Bjarne Stroustrup and that was his advice to me.  Calling `func` will need to qualify which one is being called.

Comment: @Eljay, that will work! and thanks, But now there's this problem: The compiler will complain about this `AMBIGUOUS` if we try to create an Instance of this `ClassTwo` and try to call the inherited operator `func()`. But over-all today it solve my primary problem. I'm greatful.

Comment: The right thing to do is not to use `final` at all.

Comment: @Eljay You could just define and call `func2` in `ClassTwo` without going to all this hassle.

Answer (score 0):

What I've got looks like this:

```
class InterfaceOne {
     public:
          void run() final { this->func(); }
     protected:
          virtual void func() = 0;
}

class ClassOneHelper : public InterfaceOne {
     public:
          void func() final override;
}

class ClassTwoHelper : public InterfaceOne {
     public:
          void func() final override;
}

class ClassOne : public ClassOneHelper {
    protected:
         auto fieldOne;
}

class ClassTwo : public ClassOne, public ClassTwoHelper {
    
}
```

And Then create a polymorph-instance:

```
InterfaceOne* iOne = new ClassTwoHelper();
iOne->run();  // (public access-modifier)
iOne->func(); // call only at inherited rule (protected access-modifier)
```

WARNING: There's a problem, When we try to create a direct-instance of `ClassTwo` or `ClassOne` and calling the inherited operator, the compiler will complain: saying it is `AMBIGIOUS`.

> This Instance didn't know which operator to use/invoke, For the reason that this Child Class has a sever-repeated/duplicated inheritance from `ClassTwoHelper` and From indirect `ClassOneHelper` of `ClassOne`.
>
> ```
> ClassTwo* cTwo = new ClassTwo();
> cTwo->run();  // ERROR: Ambigious
> cTwo->func(); // ERROR: Ambigious
>                                  // figure 2.0
> ```

In other words if you want this option;

```
// this child class is free on inheriting `ClassTwo` however it must not override `func()`
class ClassMalicious : public ClassTwo { 
     public:
           void func() override; // this func cannot be over written
}
```

Then never call inherited members created by a direct instance show in ***figure 2.0***